# Trackpad and mouse different scrolling directions

Tags: macbook-pro

Is it possible to have the trackpad scrolling direction different from mouse connected to the MBP?

EDIT: Found the solution, check my answer below.

Comment: Hum, that's weird. While the *trackpad* and the *mouse* have different configuration panels, I can't get them to interact differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution.

Apparently you can solve it using software. I downloaded Scrollreverser, which is free: http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/

This allows you to control the scroll direction both on the mouse and trackpad separately.

Really cool.

Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry but for me that's no viable solution, as it's closed-source. https://twitter.com/francoisbecker/status/430639783174348800

Comment: @moala: right — as opposed to OS X, the entire source of which you can browse at will.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (the scrollreverser one didn't work for me):

- Download and install [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/).
- Use the following configuration:

  - Wheel:

    - Roll Up -> 3 x Scroll Down
    - Roll Down -> 3 x Scroll Up

[image]

Source: http://developingandstuff.blogspot.de/2013/07/make-mouse-and-trackpad-scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a mouse and a trackpad at the same time. I wanted the trackpad scrolling natural while the mouse scrolling reverse.

There are couple of applications fixing that issue, me personally think that Mos is the most sophisticated. It also fixes some scrolling smoothness issues that the most non-apple mouses have and many more features.

You can download from here: https://mos.caldis.me/

I hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Especially, please edit to turn this into an actual answer to the specific problem described in the question, and less like a product placement.